# How do I fix the "Cannot save event" or "No Calendar Set" issue?

Tags: iphone, ios, calendar

Currently i am working on Calendar Events. I implemented code using [Link](https://github.com/fostah/iOS-Event-Edit-Example), but its raising alert like cannot save event no Calendar set.How can i fix this type of issue, can any one help me please..

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Show us some code that you are using that causes the problem.

Comment: @JustSid : attached link same code i implemented

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have configure a calendar in you device.
Goto `Settings ->Mail,Contacts, Calendars`
and add a calendar there. It will work.
[see this](http://www.ehow.com/how_7373342_add-remove-iphone-calendars.html)

Comment: Under that i have only 4 options New Invitation Alerts , Time Zone Support, Sync, Default Alert time. I do have any other option to add calendar

Comment: see the link, added in the answer plz see

Comment: thanks dude but where can i find the server name for my iphone calendar

Comment: you can just simply configure any test gmail account on your device. It will add all the necessary things.